# Login or registration is very slow from any Xmpp Client

Tags: arch-linux, xmpp, ejabberd

I've set up Ejabberd successfully everything works as it should.
Only the login or a registration takes a long time, sometimes over 20 seconds.
DNS entries match, config, SSL certificate too, needed ports are open.

do not know why it takes so long.
What could it be, if you need something logs, config or other things please tell me.

Comment: I would recommend checking your client to see where the delay happens: before actually opening the stream (i.e. xml stanza `<stream…) or there is a hiccup during xml stanza exchange - and if so, at what moment.

Comment: It may be a mismatch between ipv4 and ipv6. If you have configure ejabberd to listen only on ipv4 or ipv6 interface and if your client tries the other one first, it may take a while before it falls back to the other interface.